# Using the latest value from IObservable

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, system.reactive

I've got three `IObservable` of types `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz`. In addition, there is a method defined as:

```
void DoWork(Foo foo);
```

The `IObservable` are defined elsewhere as `Subject` and `OnNext` is called from time to time.

Whenever new data is available (defined by some Where queries), I want to call the `DoWork` method with the latest `Foo` value. If no `Foo` values were generated the method should not be called.

What is the easiest way to do that?

To be more specific, see the following example. I'd like to call `DoWork` when `bar` or `baz` change, with the latest `foo` (`f.id == 1`):

```
void Wire(IObservable<Foo> foo, IObservable<Bar> bar, IObservable<Baz> baz)
{
    foo.Where(f => f.Id == 1)
        .Subscribe(f => DoWork(f));
}
```

Comment: And the relation/interaction between IObservable and the streams is ...

Comment: See my edit regarding Subject and OnNext. Nothing too fancy

Comment: Do you mean you want to call `DoWork()` when *either* `bar` or `baz` changes?

Comment: Yes, when one of them changes

Comment: @kshahar - Why have you used `Replay`?

Comment: @Enigmativity - Because I want to use the latest Foo with Id == 1, and ignore the rest. With your original answer, whenever a new Foo is generated with a different Id the method will not be called.

Comment: @kshahar - You don't need the `Replay` - the `Where` clause is enough.

Comment: @Enigmativity - that's odd, if I use your answer directly it doesn't work. But if I define the Where clause separately (see my edit) it does work. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @kshahar - You're right. I'll change my answer shortly. The `Where` should happen before the `CombineLatest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var ubar = bar.Select(x => Unit.Default);
var ubaz = baz.Select(x => Unit.Default);

ubar.Merge(ubaz)
    .CombineLatest(foo.Where(f => f.Id == 1), (u, f) => f)
    .Subscribe(f => DoWork(f));
```

Comment: @kshahar - Isn't that what you asked for in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Do` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229804%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) on the [`Observable` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh244252%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) to do this:

```
IObservable<Foo> filteredList = foos.Where(...);

// Invoke DoWork on each instance of Foo.
filteredList.Do(DoWork);
```